# Apache configuration 2.4

Tags: linux, apache, http, centos, httpd.conf

I need to perform the following configuration on my Apache server, version 2.4, with CentOS system.

The instructions I received are as follows:

> Configuring Another Web Server to Serve the Files If another web
>   server is using port 80 on the same server as Centova Cast, you will
>   need to use this method.
>
> This method depends upon your knowledge of the other web server you
>   are using; you must be familiar enough with your web server of choice
>   to configure it appropriately. Centova Technologies cannot provide
>   support or assistance with any changes to your web server's
>   configuration.
>
> To allow "Let's Encrypt" to validate your domain ownership, you must
>   configure your web server such that any requests for files under the
>   following URI (replacing example.com with your own domain name):
>
> http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ ...are configured to
>   serve files from the following directory:
>
> /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges/ So for example, if you
>   create a file called
>   /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges/test.txt, you should be
>   able to visit http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt
>   in your browser and see the contents of the test.txt file.
>
> A few example configurations are provided below. Please note, however,
>   that differences in your web server configuration may require
>   additional settings not mentioned here.

```
Example apache:

Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges
<Directory /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges>
Options None
AllowOverride None

Apache 2.x
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfModule>

Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all granted
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I've tried everything and I can't get it to work, how should the correct configuration be done?

My configuration file is located at: **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

Comment: "I can't get it to work says little", have you tried to access the path yourself? What error do you get? what do you see in access.log and error.log? (in 2.4 to log 404 in error log you need `LogLevel core:info`)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to configure this, so I don't have any errors. I need to know which file to edit, and what to replace or insert.

Comment: define it in your configuration and see what happens